# How to write a function which will be return : Observable <ModelTemp>

Tags: angular, angular7

How to write a function which will be return : Observable .

my service:

```
 modelTemp= [{ 
    name: 'abcdefghijk'
 }];   
 get(): Observable<ModelTemp> {
    return this.modelTemp;
 }
```

In service the method the variable is displayed red:

*Returned expression type {name: string}[] is not assignable to type Observable less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Checks TypeScript called function parameters , return values , assigned expressions to be of correct type*

How to fix this error?

my component:

```
 model: ModelTemp; 

    constructor(private getService: GetService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
      this.generate();
    }

    generate() {
      this.getService.get()
        .subscribe((modelData) => { 
          this.model = modelData;
        });
    }
```

my interface:

```
   export interface ModelTemp {
      name: string; 
   }
```

I do not know where I'm making a mistake. The model component should be declared differently (in this way):
    modelPage: ModelPage;
or so:
    modelPage: ModelPage[];

In my the browser returns me an error:

*this.getService.get(...).subscribe is not a function at TempComponent.push../src/app/temp/temp.component.ts.TempComponent.generate.*

I want to use the subscribe method. Which will return the model (interface ModelTemp)

How to correct the code?

How to write a function which will be return : Observable .

Answer (score 3):

use rxjs operators like  **of** to return an Observable

```
import {of} from 'rxjs';

 get(): Observable<ModelTemp> {
  return of(this.modelTemp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
modelTemp: BehaviorSubject<ModelTemp[]> = new BehaviorSubject([{ 
    name: 'abcdefghijk'
}]);

get(): BehaviorSubject <ModelTemp[]> {
    return this.modelTemp;
}
```

This returns a Subject that you can subscribe to.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what sort of control you need over the resulting observable.

- If you need only to satisfy a requirement that the already-known data be in an observable, then [Fateh Mohamed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56740149/5507494) has the right idea in returning a [`of(this.modelTemp)`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/of.html).
- But if you need to emit future values as the ModelTemp array changes, then [German Burgardt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56740166/5507494) is on a better track by providing you a Subject on which you can call `behaviorSubject.next(newModelTemp)` which will emit to anyone who subscribed to your [Behavior Subject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html).  You may also wish to prevent other callers from emitting from this behavior subject by returning only the result of `behaviorSubject.asObservable()` and keeping the behavior subject itself private.
- Lastly, if the ModelTemp array contains a set of values that should be emitted in succession by the observable, use [`from(this.modelTemp)`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html).

Answer (score 0):

the method: `get(): Observable<ModelTemp> { return of(this.modelTemp); }` will reset the error: `Type 'Observable<{ name: string; }[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<ModelTemp>'. Property 'name' is missing in type '{ name: string; }[]' but required in type 'ModelTemp'.`