# How to change my promise to an observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a service with a selectedLanguage variable, but I got a null value instead of the real value

```
data: any = {};
  selectedLanguage = 'en';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private storage: Storage) {
  }

  async use(lang: string): Promise<{}> {
    lang = lang ? lang : await this.storage.get('lang');
    return new Promise<{}>((resolve) => {
      const langPath = `assets/i18n/${lang || 'en'}.json`;
      this.selectedLanguage = lang;
      this.storage.set('lang', this.selectedLanguage);
      this.http.get<{}>(langPath).subscribe(
        translation => {
          this.data = Object.assign({}, translation || {});
          return resolve(this.data);
        },
        () => {
          this.data = {};
          return resolve(this.data);
        }
      );
    });
  }

  get(): string {
    return this.selectedLanguage;
  }
}
```

In the component.ts file i use it but not in a good way

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  imgError = false;
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  selectedLanguage: string;




  constructor(
    public storage: Storage,
    private translateService: TranslateService,
    private alertController: AlertController,
    private translate: TranslatePipe
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedLanguage = this.translateService.selectedLanguage;
```

How can I use selectedLanguage as an observable to not get a null value?

Comment: In your method, declare observable and return an observable instead of promise. In the calling method, just subscribe. On subscribe, you will get the value.

Comment: Aw okay, thank you for your help. Maybe can you write it to me. I am really really beginner in programming and i don't know how is it possible yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some example how to set language with observables is below

```
   setLang(lang: string): Observable<void> {
        return fromPromise(this.storage.get('lang')).pipe(flatMap((lang) => {
            const langPath = `assets/i18n/${lang || 'en'}.json`;
            return this.http.get<{}>(langPath)
        }), map(data => {
            return ...doSomeDataMapping
        }), tap((result) => {
            this.data = result;
            this.selectedLanguage = lang
        }))
    }
```

`tap` part is needed only if you really need to have stateful service.

If You need async getter for selected language field your tap will look like below :

```
 tap((result) => {
            this.data$.next(result);
            this.selectedLanguage$.next(lang)
        })
```

and you'll need :

```
private data$ = new BehaviorSubject(initialValue);
private selectedLanguage$ = new BehaviorSubject(initialValue);
```

at the top.

then getters will be

```
    getSelectedLanguage$(): Observable<string> {
        return this.selectedLanguage$;
    }
```

called in component

```
this.selectedLanguage$ = this.translateService.getSelectedLanguage$();
```

and used with `async` pipe in view for example

Comment: Thank you! It's working now! And is it possible to write this function without using async/await but with promise?

Comment: Of course it is but what for :D

Comment: I'm working on a project as an intern and my "mentor" doesn't like this solution with observable, although it works... :S he wants the function to go without async / await but stay in sync with promise. Can you help me with this too? :D

Comment: Change mentor or ask why he needs Promise method where whole Angular is based on observables

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `Observable` thats observer receives the value of your `Promise`.

```js
const { Observable } = rxjs;

const promise$ = new Promise(resolve => resolve('Success!'))

const observable$ = new Observable(observer => promise$.then(value => observer.next(value)))

observable$.subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

**Step by Step:**

The `Promise` is created and the value `Success!` is directly `resolved`. Also a `Observable` is created and the body of the `observer-function` listens for a value of the `Promise`.

**Why do we get an `value` although the `Promise` was set and resolved before the Observable was created?**

`Promises` are not synchronously processed. They are `microtasks`. Those are processed after `makrotasks`. RxJS by default uses a [Scheduler](https://rxjs.dev/guide/scheduler) to process each value that goes through its pipes/operators/functions. The default scheduler (you can read it at the bottom of the link) is an `asyncScheduler` that is internal some kind of `setTimeout` mechanism and therefore a `makrotask`.

**Sum:**

The `Observable` receives the value of the `Promise` as its processed before the `Promise` value.

Its a complicated topic. The `mikro-` and `markotask` stuff relates to the `JavaScript Event Queue`. This [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&t=895s) explained it very well to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a method that returns observable. In your ngOnInit(), call this method and onSubscription you can would get the value. Once your method execution is completed return observable value. I've given a sample code. You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56740089/how-to-write-a-function-which-will-be-return-observable-modeltemp) to get more info.

```
get(langObtained): Observable<String> {
    let lang= langObtained;
    return of(lang);
  } 

ngOninit(){
   this.get('hi').subscribe(response=>{
//use the response
    });
}
```